# @selector equivalent in AppleScriptObjC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm working with an `NSDatePicker` and an `NSTextField` to update the text field whenever the `NSDatePicker`'s value changes.

In Objective-C, I would use this method:

```
     datePicker addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(dateChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged
```

I've converted this method into the following AppleScriptObjC code:

```
     datePicker's addTarget_action_forControlEvents_(me, ¬ 
                  @selector(dateChanged_), ¬
                  (current application's UIControlEventValueChanged))
```

However, this causes the build to fail. In place of `@selector(dateChanged_)`, I've also tried `"@selector(dateChanged:)"`, `"@selector(dateChanged_)"`, and `dateChanged_`; no luck so far.

What is the correct way to convert this method to AppleScriptObjC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tried, but it should be

```
datePicker's addTarget_action_forControlEvents_(me, "dateChanged:", (current application's UIControlEventValueChanged))
```

Comment: `-[NSDatePicker addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` I tried the code in `awakeFromNib()` and `applicationWillFinishLaunching_()`; neither worked, unfortunately. Do I need to coerce the `NSDatePicker` to a `UIControl`? I figured it would just inherit the methods from `UIControl` implicitly.

Comment: Now I see, NSDatePicker inherits from NSControl, not UIControl. Use the proper selector of NSControl.